# Why does using "this" on an checkbox event listener not return the dom object, but rather the window object?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener on a checkbox that passes a few arguments using "this", however for some reason it doesn't work.

Upon sending "this" to the console, I can see that unlike my other event listeners that I'm using for text input and select nodes, that it's returning the entire window object

The code I'm using:

```
document.getElementById("nightMode").addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log(this)
})
```

What I would expect to see in console:

```
<input id="nightMode" type="checkbox" />
```

What is actually being sent to the console:

```
Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using an arrow function ( `() => { ... }` ). Replace it with a normal function ( `function() { ... }` ).

Arrow functions don't have a `this` of their own. It cannot change; `this` inside an arrow function will always point to whatever `this` was **at the point in time when the function was *declared***.

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead:

```
<input id="nightMode" type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you use arrow function, you have binded `this` of your global scope ( Window ) to your handler function.

Try to use normal function decalration instead: `function () { ... }`